# error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000002) in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, c++-cli

I am creating a new abstract class in C++/CLI and have run into a strange error. There are many questions similar to this one but none of the answers could help me.

In this new class, I get the following error:

```
error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000002) Foo::execute
```

This is the h-file:

```
#pragma once
using namespace System::IO::Ports;
using namespace System;

public ref class Foo
{
protected:
    SerialPort^ port;
public:
    Foo(SerialPort^ sp);
    virtual array<Byte>^ execute();
};
```

This is the cpp-file:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Foo.h"

Foo::Foo(SerialPort^ sp)
{
    this->port = sp;
}
```

Note that when I comment out the `virtual array<Byte>^ execute();` line, everything compiles perfectly. Also, when I remove the `virtual` modifier and add an implementation of `execute()` in the cpp-file, it works as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already gave the answer yourself:

> Also, when I remove the virtual modifier and add an implementation of execute() in the cpp-file, it works as well.

You declared the method `execute` in the header, but it's implementation is missing. That's exactly what the linker error is telling you.
In this case the declaration as `virtual` does not matter.

If you want to create an abstract class, you can find further details in numerous articles online (e.g. [Wikibooks: Abstract Classes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes))

Comment: Thank you. I will accept this answer and upvote it when I have enough reputation. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have to either implement the method or remove the declaration from the header. (virtual keyword doesn't matter in this case)

Please, ask a question, if you have any.